# Convert a number to time format HH:mm:ss

Tags: extended-sql

I am getting an integer in the input, for eg: `032614`. I want to convert this into a time of format `HH:mm:ss`.
For eg: `032614` should be converted to `03:26:14`. Please let know if this can be done by ESQL

I have tried the below code but it fails with:

> 'Failed to match literal error'

```
CAST(cReqTimestamp AS TIMESTAMP FORMAT 'HH:mm:ss');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a ESQL code snippet, target variable will have the output you need.

```
    DECLARE source INT 032614;
    DECLARE target CHARACTER;
    DECLARE pattern CHARACTER '00,00,00';
    SET target = REPLACE(CAST(source AS CHARACTER FORMAT pattern),',',':');
```

You can go through the below link to get further information on CAST.
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ak05610_.htm

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that there is no direct supported cast between INTEGER and TIMESTAMP so you need to go indirectly via a CAST to CHAR first.

```
CAST(CAST(cReqTimestamp AS CHAR FORMAT '000000') AS TIMESTAMP FORMAT 'HH:mm:ss');
```

Use zeroes in your pattern to ensure that any leading zeroes are retained.